# Inadequate cookie attributes in spring application

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In spring MVC application the cookie attribute- path is set to root(/) and should be configured with the cookie attribute path to a specific domain path.

In web.xml file made the below changes. But still issue is not resolved. jsessionid is set to the root path, but another cookie with name inc10 is not set to root path. Kindly help.

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
   <cookie-config>
      <path>/MyApp</path>
      <http-only>true</http-only>
     <secure>false</secure>
   </cookie-config>
   <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

[image]

Comment: inc10 or imc10?

Comment: sorry for mistake imc10

Comment: Please check the screenshot, imc10 is set to the root path. You said its not. Vice-versa you said in the text that the JSESSIONID is set to the root-path but the screenshot is different. I think your question contradicts your question.